# How to add lines/stripes to a shape or image in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need help... a "Illustrators for Dummies" step by step instructions if possible.  I am new to all this...working on a project.

Basically what I'm looking for... how would you go about creating the American flag inside of a blank rectangle in Illustrator?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There are step by step [tutorials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Illustrator+tutorial+american+flag)

Comment: Unless you need to create the flag specifically to learn how... I'd merely Google search for free America Flag vector files. There are a whole lot out there available for free.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly sugggest you to take illustrator classes on youtube so you cover many basics. The stackexchange platform usually discourages basic tutorials. However here are few methods you can look to create it.

**Create a pattern**

```
1) Create a new rectangle with stroke: none, fill: red (for flag stripe)
2) Ctrl+C, Ctrl+F (to duplicate the rectangle)
3) Drag the newly created duplicate so it's top edge is snapped with the bottom of firt rectangle
4) Make its fill: white
5) Select both rectangle and from the menu select Object > Pattern > Make 

6) Select the rectangle where you want to fill with stripes.
7) Menu (Window > Swatches) to open swatches panel
8) Click on your newly created pattern)
```

**Clipping Mask**

```
1) Create a Rectangle (one stripe in a flag)
2) Alt + Drag downwards to take a copy with an equal distance as of it's width
3) Ctrl+D (Command+D mac) for duplicates
4) Select these rectangles and click on Menu (Object > Compond Path > Make)
5) Drag your rectangle on these stripes (Ojbect > Arrange > Bring to Front)
6) Select both objects (Your existing rectangle and stripes) and click (Object > Clipping Mask > Make
```